# TestResult not shown properly in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

[image: TestResult for Protractor]

I am using WebStorm to run my testcases built in Protractor. I have all the modules installed using npm. As you can see from the image. The green "**.**" is for pass and red **"F"** is for Fail. Earlier i used to get green **"P"** for pass.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here. The same behaviour is shown from command prompt also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not configurable by default. The `.`, `*` and `F` constants for passed, pending and failed specs are [hardcoded](https://github.com/juliemr/minijasminenode/blob/master/lib/reporter.js#L96) into the `minijasminenode` default reporter that `Protractor` uses under-the-hood.

What you can do is to create a [custom reporter](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html), define the [`specDone` callback](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html#section-specDone) and provide custom characters for passed, pending and failed specs. Not tested.

Or, an easier option would to switch to [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter) which provides a more robust and nice looking output and makes the constants configurable:

```
{
  prefixes: {
    success: '✓ ',
    failure: '✗ ',
    pending: '* '
  }
}
```

Comment: Switched to jasmine-spec-reporter for now. I think I'll write a custom reporter to meet the requirements later.